# How to read key:value pair in text file with no line separator in Java

Tags: java

I have a file of the format

`Reference:adfafddafafExpiryDate:1019CallbackStatus:200`

Comment: How do you say what is key? CamelCase ?

Comment: So how would you know the difference between `adfafaddafafExpiryData` ?

Comment: That won't be possible unless the keys or values follow a strict form, e.g. keys always start with an uppercase letter and values are always numbers etc. But from what i see here, values can be letters, too. Where did you get this dirty file?

Comment: if they keys are a predefined set, (known) and if values can have a phrase that is similar to a key, it should be all lower (for example) if so then you might be able to parse such input, and do they appear in the same order always ?

Comment: Please show us a hexdump of that file

Comment: Are all the possible keys known?

Comment: Yes the keys are CamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys and values follows the specific patterns then you can use the Apche String utils to get the key value pairs as below:

```
 String value = StringUtils.substringBetween("Reference:", "ExpiryDate:")
```

now the variable value will contain `adfafddafaf` put it in a map for future use.

```
 keyValueMap.put("Reference",value);
```

do the same for rest of the values.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way of determining the end of a value of a key if there is no seperator between the value and the next key.

Comment: unless they key(s) are a known set

Comment: @Yazan yeah that too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming file have strict rules:
Colon should present after every word even value is blank.
Ref:test:New::Hobby:Coding 
Key can not null.

Then we can split file text by alternate colon.
we will further split every string by colon and store first element as key and second as value in Map.

Comment: Are you suggesting `adfafddafafExpiryDate` should be a single entry, and not `adfafddafaf` and `ExpiryDate`?

Comment: I thought file text have colon after every value.  I am suggesting we should put a delimiter after ever value.